# Django AttributeError: 'MyModel' object has no attribute 'username'

Tags: python, django

I have a model, `MyModel` that is linked via *ForeignKey* to Django's `User` model. MyModel was initially linked using `models.OneToOneField` but I later changed it to `models.ForeignKey` and also deleted some fields.

**Initial Models.py:**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from myapp.models import mymodel

class MyModel(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, blank=True, null=True, related_name='mymodel')
    username = models.CharField(max_length=145, blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
```

**Editted Model.py:**

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True, related_name='mymodel')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
```

I deleted *migration folder* and my **DB** and recreated them anew but each time I try retrieving data from MyModel via `MyModel.objects.all()` or `User` object I get **AttributeError: 'MyModel' object has no attribute 'username'**

Comment: Your `db` is behind the Django model by some migrations. Do `makemigrations` and `migrate`

Comment: @MosesKoledoye I did that `python manage.py makemigrations myapp` and then `python manage.py migrate` after recreating my schema but the problem still persists.

Comment: delete migration file and create new db and try syncdb

Comment: @vikramsinghchandel I have already done that as stated in the question.

Comment: which fields are actually present in the table? `./manage.py dbshell` then check the table

Comment: which db backend are you using?

Comment: @seeN I use **MySQL** as the backend.

Answer (score 0):

Your updated model doesn't have an attribute `username`, because the field name is `user`.